# How to work with arduino softwareserial communication?

Tags: arduino, communication

This is my first project using Bluetooth module HC-05. I am using two of these modules. One is connected to an Arduino Nano(slave) and another one is connected to an Arduino Uno(master). I have paired them through AT commands.

For testing, I was giving a pulse in pin 7 on the Nano. If there is a pulse, then slave will send character "1". If not, then it will send "0".

In the Uno there is an LED connected to pin 13. If the master receives '1', then the LED will on and if receives '0', the LED will remain off.

here is my source code ----------

slave code=>
[image: slave code]

master code=>
[image: master code]

The Arduino IDE isn't showing any bug, but the code is not working at all. Although I am giving a pulse in pin 7 of the Nano, the LED is remaining off in the Uno. I am at a loss now. I have a lot to do after this and my project submission is knocking at the door. Please help me as soon as possible.

Comment: Screenshots of text? Why didn't you also print and scan them?

Comment: sorry.I was in a hurry then.

Comment: but creating and posting a screenshot takes much longer than copy/paste...

Comment: How do you have the bluetooth modules installed? What are they wired to? How are they powered? How did you pair and configure them? It looks like you're trying to use a baud rate of 38400 instead of the default 9600 - did you follow the procedure to enable that?

Comment: (slave-nano):   VCC=5v;GND=GND;TXD=2(RX);RXD=3(TX);EN=5v--------------------------------------------------------------(master-uno): VCC=5v;GND=GND;TXD=2(RX);RXD=3(TX);EN=5v

Comment: well,i fixed it.........at last.....

Comment: @RakibulIslamPrince - How did you fix it? What was the problem? You can answer your own question (and accept the answer!), and then you can help future visitors who have the same problem.

Comment: @RakibulIslamPrince please post an answer to this question with how you fixed this. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had connected some pins the wrong way.

I had connected the "EN" pin with 5V even after pairing. I was out of my brain. As soon as it came to my sight I disconnected the "EN" pin from 5V. After a few seconds it started to work....